# Get remote client ip address NodeJS, ExpressJs

Tags: node.js, express, clientip

I am trying to get client's ip address with Express js, code is as follows:

```
var ip;
if (req.headers['x-forwarded-for']) {
    ip = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'].split(",")[0];
} else if (req.connection && req.connection.remoteAddress) {
    ip = req.connection.remoteAddress;
} else {
    ip = req.ip;
}
ip = (ip.length < 15 ? ip : (ip.substr(0, 7) === '::ffff:' ? ip.substr(7) : undefined));


console.log('ip address',ip);
```

But every time I am getting localhost ip address not **Public ip address**, 
so how can I get public ip address instead of localhost ip address?
can anyone help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check server infrastructure has load balancers, proxies, etc... in front of your actual server, the above local values may return the local server, not what the actual public IP/port that the client originally connected to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the last IP of the `x-forwarded-for` header.

For example, on aws :

> the last IP address in the list is the IP address of the client
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/x-forwarded-headers.html#x-forwarded-for